# Set HTML content to the mail body of MFMailComposeViewController's view

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, xcode4, messageui

I'm using MessageUI framework to compose email in my app. I want set HTML content for the mail body.

So I refered [Mugunthkumar's blog](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/) and I coded as follow,

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];


// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Fill out the email body text    
NSString *pageLink = @"http://mugunthkumar.com/mygreatapp"; // replace it with yours
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://link-to-mygreatapp"; // replate it with yours
NSString *emailBody =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n&lt;h3&gt;Sent from &lt;a href = '%@'&gt;MyGreatApp&lt;/a&gt; on iPhone. &lt;a href = '%@'&gt;Download&lt;/a&gt; yours from AppStore now!&lt;/h3&gt;", @"title", pageLink, iTunesLink];


[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

When I ran the app and go to the email compose view, I'm getting the following mail body,

[image]

I'm using XCode4 and iOS 4.3. 
I can not see any issue with my code. 
But I need to insert clickable URLs to my mail body.

please help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send an HTML-formatted email, it is wrong to escape the HTML tags in the email body. Use `</a>` instead of `&lt;/a&gt;` etc.